# Linkstation 420 NAS keeps dropping from network

Tags: networking, router, nas, dd-wrt

I have a problem with my Linkstation 420 4TB NAS. My NAS keeps dropping off my network - I installed it a couple of days ago (a used one) and haven't got it working.

I can be on the web admin site and browse for some time and then suddenly the site goes into not responding. I can go into my TP-Link WR1043ND router (with DD-WRT) and I can see on my status site for my LAN that the Linkstation just drops off. I'm then unable to access anything, neither the drivers nor the website. The device can be working for 10 mins or 33 or 1 hour, I then have to go and cut the power, wait a little bit and then can turn it on again.

I have updated the device with the newest firmware and reapplied the firmware, reformatted the device and tried with a new network cable - all of which did nothing. The device has a static IP address, so I've tried setting one with DHCP reservation for the MAC address and setting it on the device but still no difference.

Does anyone have an idea what can be wrong or what I can do to troubleshoot? I am about to send it to RMA but would like to troubleshoot first so I don't waste time with the company.

Comment: You've tried eveything, unless its overheating its time to RMA it.

Comment: Yea thnaks, I have recived the rma papers and will send it back in, I will get a new device.